# How to run the Wear app with handled app with out any signing? I mean developer debug mode

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

While developing wear application,Every time i am following steps

Create two apps, one for wear and other one for handled app

Signing wear app and place it handled app(Raw folder)

again signing handled app and installing in mobile

Every time doing like this very difficult.
I want to know how to develop wear app in debug mode not in release mode.

I mean How to run handled app directly from eclipse to run wear app with out any signing procedure every time.

I found this from developer site.
http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html

Comment: How did you solve it? I have the same "problem" that you. Can you easily connect your wear app with you phone app to sync data without signing them?

Comment: Simply i started using Android Studio :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to sign your project, all you do is go to your avd manager and open your android wear emulator or have your android wear device connected to your computer(make sure you have the correct drivers for the device I am not sure because i usually an emulator). Then once that is up and running, run your main activity and eclipse will give you the option on which device to run your activity on. Select android wear, and soon your activity will be running on your wear device/emulator.

This website has all lot of useful info for these types of questions
http://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html

Comment: But i have data to sync in between wearable device and handled app. if i ran separately it was not syncing data or there is no communication between those two devices. For example i have a button in mobile , when i click it will start an activity in wearable device. This was not happening when i ran separately

Answer (score 1):

You can either debug and send build to you watch by connecting it with a cable or via bluetooth. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html

The wearable basically works like your mobile. Turn on adb debugging and then you can deploy and run your app.

Comment: But i have data to sync in between wearable device and handled app.   if i ran separately it was not syncing data or there is no communication between those two devices.  For example i have a button in mobile , when i click it will start an activity in wearable device.  This was not happening when i ran separately.